# Design and implementation of a 2-3 tree with polymorphism

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, tree, polymorphism

I have to implement a 2-3 tree using a base class of a `node` and derived class of `leaf` and an `innernode` (i.e both "are-a" node).

But I don't understand how to start with the insertion in simple cases. Since we call the methods of `node` to insert, how is it supposed to know if what we insert needs to be an `innernode` or a `leaf`? And how does a node supposed to change itself to a `leaf` or an `innernode`?

Any tips/ideas on how to approach this?

Here's the structure, I didn't get very far though.

```
typedef int TreeKey;

class node {
public:
    virtual ~node() {}

    virtual void insert(TreeKey k, string d);
    virtual void deletenode(TreeKey k);
    virtual void findnode();
    virtual node * findnode(TreeKey key);

protected:
    struct info {
        TreeKey key;
        string data;
    };
    node* parent=nullptr;
};

class leaf : node {
    info i;
public:
    virtual void insert(TreeKey k, string d);


};

class innerNode : node {
    vector<info> inf;
    vector<node*> vect;

public:
    virtual void insert(TreeKey k, string d);


};
```

Note: in this 2-3 tree, the data sits only in the leaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing things is as follows. There are others.

Have 4 separate classes: a 2-leaf-node, a 3-leaf-node, a 2-internal-node and a 3-internal-node. This solution gets rid of vectors and so minimises dynamic allocations.

One inserts an element, not a node. Each node knows what to do with inserted element. An internal node passes the element to one of the child nodes. A leaf node absorbs the element.

A 2-node absorbs an element by becoming a 3-node. A 3-node absorbs an element by becoming two 2-nodes, and passing an element back to its parent to absorb. The parent then itself changes and may pass an element up. This continues until some 2-node changes to a 3-node (its parent doesn't need to change, only replace its child pointer), or an element propagates all the way back to the root, and a new root is created.

How a node "becomes" something else? It cannot. Instead, it creates the new thing(s) it should become, copies its information to the new thing(s), returns the newly created thing(s) to the caller, and deletes itself. The caller then either replaces its old child with the newly created one, or itself "becomes" something else.

The `insert` method signature of the node could look like this:

```
 typedef enum {none, expand23, split322} action;
 action Node::insert(info& element, Node*& newNode1, Node*& newNode2);
```

If the node was a 2-node and it became a 3-node, the method creates a new 3-node and passes it back in `newNode1`. The parent has to replace the corresponding child pointer upon seeing `expand23`. The parent itself doesn't expand or split, so *its* `insert` returns `none`.

If the node was a 3-node and it splits, the method creates two new 2-nodes and passes them back in `newNode1` and `newNode2`. It also passes back an element for that the parent to absorb. The parent will do either `expand23` or `split322` depending on what type it is.

If the root returns `split322`, a new root is created

<s>"in this 2-3 tree, the data sits only in the leaves" — just noticed this remark. I'm not sure how this could ever work. A 2-3 tree has either 1 or 2 data items in each node, not just leaves. It cannot work otherwise. So I pretty much ignore this remark.</s>

If you don't want to have separate classes for 2- and 3-nodes, then you don't need `expand23` because a 2-node can turn into a 3-node without having to delete itself. `split322` remains the same. I would not use vectors in this case. Since leaf nodes only store copies of keys that exist elsewhere, they can be stored as 3 (smart) pointers to keys (not an array, just 3 separate variables). You distinguish between a 2-node and a 3-node by looking at the third pointer. If it's a nullptr, this is a 2-node. Same thing about data in the leaves, store it in 3 separate pointers.

Comment: About the last part, keys can be everywhere but the actual data is supposed to be only in the leaves, (I saw that there's another version but that's how we're supposed to do it). Here's an example: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/10.23TREE.html

Comment: Why it wouldn't work if data is kept only in leaves?

Comment: Aha, they store copies of keys in the internal nodes, and keys and data in the leaves. This does work. Nothing the answer really depends on what exactly is stored in the nodes, the algorithms stay the same.

Comment: Alright, so to clear one more thing, you store a pointer to a base class node outside, say in main? And use its methods to trickle down the tree?

Comment: So at the start 'node.insert(element)' will create a leaf and check where it can store it? How you could keep the outside pointer then if it is being deleted when turning from a node to a leaf and to an inner node?

Comment: Create a separate class Tree that would store a pointer to the root node. The reason is that sometimes you need to create a new root. This cannot be handled by main.

Comment: Alright I think I'm getting this. One last thing (I hope) why are you against using vectors? Isn't it easier to check its size instead of checking for null pointers? And by smart pointers, do you mean `shared_ptr`?

Comment: If you can see a place where you iterate over the vector, or use it with an index that is not known statically, go ahead and use it. Otherwise you are doing something wrong. Smart pointers come in several flavours, shared_ptr is one, unique_ptr and weak_ptr are two others. Use whatever fits.